# ngOnInit function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

Can somebody explain what's going on in this ngOnInit function? Need clarity with this.load() being called twice, once in the beginning then afterwards in subscribe

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.load();

this.router.events
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.reset();
    this.load();
  });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Are you familiar with RxJS observables? Have you read the Angular router docs? Please [edit] to be specific.

Comment: I just need clarity with this.load() being called twice, once in the beginning then afterwards in subscribe

Comment: Then include that in your question. But it loads once when the component is initialised then again every time the router emits a navigation end event.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The load() function called twice because:

1. First on component loading then init() method is called.
2. its called in router event subscriptions.